# Using apostrophe in email subject while sent email via gmail api creating an issue

Tags: c#, email, gmail, gmail-api, google-developers-console

While sent email using below `subject` which `apostrophe` replacing with another characters

`Actual` Subject :     We’ll make 100,800 cold calls for you

`Mail Shows` Subject : Weâ€™ll make 100,800 cold calls for you

Issue happens when I'm sent email via api , when sent email from SMTP it's working fine

Please check my api code below

```
 string msg = "From: " + FromName + "<" + From + ">" + " \r\n" +
                                 "To: " + ToName + "<" + To + ">" + " \r\n" +
                                 "BCC: " + BCCEmail + " \r\n" +
                                 "Subject: " + Subject + " \r\n" +
                                 "Message-ID: mID_" + messageID + "\r\n" +
                                   "References: "+encryptMessageID + "\r\n" +
                                     "In-Reply-To: " + encryptMessageID + "\r\n" +
                                 "Content-Type: " + contentType + "; charset=us-ascii\r\n\r\n" + Body;

                dynamic objSendMsg = new { raw = commonFunction.Base64UrlEncode(msg) };
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageThreadID))
                    objSendMsg = new { raw = commonFunction.Base64UrlEncode(msg), threadId = messageThreadID };

                var _objSendMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objSendMsg);
                var strSendMsg = new StringContent(_objSendMsg, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

**When same content i'm applying in body with apostrophe working fine for body**

Please check attached screenshot

[Email copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3os4K.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to base64_encode of the subject header your sending it as plain text. the API is getting confused.

```
Subject: " +  Convert.ToBase64String(Subject) + " \r\n" +
```

Comment: not working for me  showing subject like below    V2U/bGwgbWFrZSAxMDAsODAwIGNvbGQgY2FsbHMgZm9yIHlvdQ==

Comment: @DalmTo is there any solution from your end

Comment: try Base64UrlEncode.  Your encoding the body you need to encode the subject as well.